# Is it possible to specify schema in the database query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database with several schemas.

In my c# code I have a base context that does some neat logic that I want all of my other contexts to be able to do. We'll call it "ParentContext". Basically ParentContext has access to the user Schema and table.

I have several other contexts that inherit from ParentContext. example child1Context, child2Context....

ParentContext never gets instantiated.

What I need to know is if there is a way to specify in ParentContext or the childContexts when doing custom logic that needs to access a user who is in a specific schema, to use the appropriate schema. IE.

```
SELECT "Name" FROM "UserSchema"."UserTable" WHERE Id = 1;
```

Instead of

```
SELECT "Name" FROM "Child2ContextSchema"."UserTable" WHERE Id = 1;
```

To be clear, I have specified schema's

An example of c# code from ParentContext

```
    public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(int Id)
    {
        User user = await User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => 
        u.Id == Id);

        return user;
    }
```

I figured out one solution, but it creates another problem!
Inside of the childContexts You can specify the schema an entitiy uses inside of the OnModelCreating Method:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User", "UserSchema");
     }
```

New Problem, Now every time I need to run a migration it will try and build that table and I'll get an exception. Can be fixed manually, but on a team of 10 dev, that's a problem that could be pretty bad. Any ideas? I tried Ignoring the entity so it won't try and build a user table when I add a new migration. However, then the context doesn't know how to talk to that table anymore.

Any Suggestions?

Also this is how the connection strings are instanciated:

```
 services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()



 .AddDbContext<Entity1>(options => 
options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString)))
        .AddDbContext<Entity2>(options => 
options.UseNpgsql(ConnectionString))
```

Comment: how do you instantiate your child contexes?

Comment: @Simonare Inside the Controller's Constructor. Then assign the constructor to a private read only variable for the constroller to use as needed.

Comment: Are you using DI?

Comment: @Simonare Yes, this is an ASP.Net Core App.  services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()

            .AddDbContext<Entity>(options => options.UseNpgsql(ConnectionString));